# Returned computer with Microsoft Account : have I compromised security?

Tags: account-security

This may not be the correct place to ask. Forgive me, if it is not.

I bought a computer from ebay second-hand and did not receive activated Windows 10. When I requested a registery key I was sent an invalid one, so the company accepted that I return it to them.

However I had logged in to Windows 10 with my name and using my Microsoft account and when I returned the computer I could find no way of erasing my existence from the computer. I sent a note with the computer to the seller.

I have changed my Microsoft account password but I am concerned that the computer I have returned will still be able to access my own microsoft account, despite that password change.

Since that is also my email password (I use outlook/hotmail) I am deeply concerned and wish now that I had held on to the computer until I had managed to resolve this issue.

I was put under pressure to return it immediately or lose my right to a refund.

I am very worried about this and I ask for some advice or if I have come to the wrong place, then advice on where to find an answer.

---

EDIT after posting.

I have now set up two-stage verification in my Microsoft account and I have also requested Microsoft's 'sign-out' process which will sign me out of all devices and apps within twenty four hours, necessitating signing back in again with the new password. (I am still on a learning curve with this.)

Comment: I don't know if you had anything to worry about originally, but based on your update you definitely don't anymore

Comment: @ConorMancone That is reassuring. Thank you.